# How to express my attitude towards a thing? treat, view, see, regard

Tags: meaning, word-choice

If I want to express my attitude towards something, what is the right way of saying it?

- I treat the delivery fee as a cost of saved time.
- I view the delivery fee as a cost of saved time.
- I see the delivery fee as a cost of saved time.
- I regard the delivery fee as a cost of saved time.

Are any of these examples correct or incorrect?

What is the most casual way?

Comment: I treat delivery fees as a cost of time saved.

Comment: Does anyone else feel like “as a cost of saved time” feels strange?  I’d prefer something like “as the cost of saving time.”

Comment: @Jim...actually I said that in a now-deleted comment. How about "as the _price_ of /for saved time"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence

> I ______ the delivery fee as a cost of saved time,

**all of the four you gave**, treat, view, see, and regard, **fit grammatically and are semantically appropriate** but they do have their individual nuances.

First, **'see' is the most natural and the most casual.** It is not informal, it is just the least rare and least academic sounding.

Then 'view', which is almost identical semantically to 'see', is the next least academic.

'Treat' and 'regard' are both the most formal, 'regard' being a bit high register because of its romance connections, and 'treat' because of its vague metaphor. Also 'treat' is more active in its conception of the object - the others are  just registering a feature.

There are other synonyms that work here: 'consider', 'recognize', 'think of', 'conceive of', 'equate...with', 'understand', and many more that might work.

The most natural and straightforward sounding would be:

> I **consider** the delivery fee as a cost of saved time.

or

> I **see** the delivery fee as a cost of saved time.